# AJAX function not working for change() jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onchange

I have a jquery as HTML form as below. I am trying to display some documents required and show a div when the user changes the options, depending on the option value.

```
<select id="constitution_id" class="form_select_constitution">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('.form_select_constitution').change(function(){
      var cid = $(this).val();
      if(cid > 2 ) {
        $('#appDiv').show();    
      }else{
        $('#appDiv').hide();    
      }
      data = 'cid='+cid;
      url = 'business_documents_available.php';


      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : url;
        data : data,
        //dataType: "json",
        error:function(resp){
                alert('Error !');
            },
            success: function(resp){
                alert(resp);
        //show_docs(resp);
            }
      });

});

function show_docs(resp) {
     //$('.json_resp_docs').html(resp.documents); 
}
```

And the `business_documents_available.php` is :

```
<?php
    include_once('include/config.php');
    include_once('validate.php');
    include_once('applicants.php');

    $cid = $_GET['cid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM doc_vehical_loan_list WHERE constitution_type = '$cid'";
    $result = $db->executeQuery($sql);

    $result_json = json_encode($result);
    //var_dump($result_json);
    //return $result_json;
    return 'HII';
?>
```

Though showing and hiding the div id `appDiv` is working , I am not getting any alert from the ajax response ! Whats happening?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: @user2625357 check in your browser's network tab whether your ajax call  is woerking or not. you can get response codes

Comment: check your browser console for javascript errors.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Where's the problem? Do some basic debugging. Check your error console to see if there are any error messages. Check your developer tools' net tab to see if the HTTP request is made, and if it is going where you expect, and if the response is what you expect.

Comment: you cant directly return 'return HII'

Comment: i thinnk passed data might be causing the problem update data like data:{cid:cid},

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

in business_documents_available.php in place of

```
return 'HII';
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple workout

html

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<select id="constitution_id" class="form_select form_select_constitution">
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.form_select_constitution').on("change",function() {

        var id = "id";  //just for reference     

        $.ajax({     
        type: "GET",   //use any kind of verb
        data: "id="+id,  //just for reference   
        url: "business_documents_available.php",
        success: function(html){
        alert(html);
        }
   });

});
</script>
</html>
```

php page

```
<?php
   echo "hey im reached";
?>
```